# Can't install app to device since updating to Xcode 5

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, ios-provisioning

I just upgraded to Xcode 5 and now I can't install my app to my device, always getting the error, "a valid provisioning profile for this executable was not found." I verified in organizer that my device can be used for development, and created a new provisioning profile for this app specifically, with my certificate and my device, but I still get this error. This was working fine yesterday with Xcode 4. Any ideas what I need to do to fix this?

Thanks...

Comment: have you specifically set a provisioning profile?

Comment: Yes, I have, and I set it to the profile I created today. Still having the same issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For me, when faced with a provisioning profile issue on Xcode 5, I was prompted to login to my Apple Developer account, upon doing so I was prompted to "Fix Issue", which, when selected, makes Xcode register the new device to a provisioning profile and refetches that profile all automatically in a couple moments' time. Xcode 5 has really impressed me with this feature. **Note:** This has been my experience with Xcode 5 GM Seed and Xcode 5.0, I have not yet tried this on Xcode 5.0.1.

Comment: I had to change my selected Provisioning Profile to "none" and do a Clean, but then the popup showed up that had the button "Fix Issue," and that worked perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

Here is what I did when I also had the same problem when I upgraded my Xcode.
Go to `Project Settings->Build Settings->Code Signing`.
You can see two separated options there: `Code Signing Identity` and `Provisioning Profile`.
Please select your `Provisioning Profile` first and then you will see your certificate identity on `Code Signing Identity` also.
Here is a screen shot for your refer.
[image: Screenshot]